# Oreo Broadcast Receivers Restrictions and Changes?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo, wifip2p

Are broadcast intent restrictions of `WiFiP2P` such as `"android.net.wifi.p2p.DISCOVERY_STATE_CHANGE"` or `"android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE"`
implicit or explicit?

Can they be received in manifest declared broadcast receivers?

Comment: Beginning with Android 8.0 (API level 26), the system imposes additional restrictions on manifest-declared receivers. If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for most implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html

Comment: That is why I am asking whether it is implicit or explicit as broadcasts specific to your app are allowed, and the intents white-listed consist of Bluetooth specific intents. So are the same allowed for wifi p2p as well.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html

Comment: its better to register through runtime

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html

Comment: Apps cannot use their manifests to register for most implicit broadcasts (that is, broadcasts that are not targeted specifically at the app).

Answer (score 0):

You can register the receiver on `Activity resume` instead of `registering in the Manifest` like

for instance :-

```
 context.registerReceiver(new WifiReceiver(),new IntentFilter("android.net.wifi.p2p.DISCOVERY_STATE_CHANGE"));
```

**Note :-**

`WifiReceiver` is a custom class which extends `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: Registering on activity will not make the intent available, once the app is killed.

Comment: **misconception** it will stay registered forever... you have to `unregister` the receiver !! @San

Comment: If you forget to unregister receiver Activity Class, the Android system reports a leaked broadcast receiver error.

Comment: Are the broadcast intents asked in question are allowed or not as the bluetooth ones are alllowed(whitelisted for manifest reciever).